# Does updating to a newer version of Windows remove files and programs

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I currently have windows 10 version 1803 and I'd like to update to the latest version (I think it's 20H1 or 20H2) using the Windows update assistant. So my question is: is it safe to update without loosing my files and will I keep all my programs installed ?

Comment: COME ON PEOPLE! ?? A DOWNVOTE?? NO COMMENT?? WTF?  Here is your point back Sofianear.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - grumpy people will always be grumpy people. Nothing you can do to fix that;) Having said that, doing anything without a known-good backup is never a good move. 999/1000 nothing will go wrong… it's just that last 1000th time… which, based on the laws of narrative imperative, will happen every other time ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin .. totally agreed!  Been doing this since.. dinasours.  ALWAYS backup or kiss your stuff goodbye.  IF you have the backup, nothing will break.  IF you don't, everything will break.

Comment: I do not know why a known correct answer was downvoted. In the vast majority of cases Windows Updates succeed. Just because 1% fail is no reason to downvote.